# How To Keep Ruby Updated on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, updating

I keep updating my Ruby to the newest version, and it somehow keeps reverting back to the old version I had installed, 2.3.7. I'm confused how or why this is happening? How can I keep it on the newest version on my computer?

Comment: This depends on your operating system and your Ruby version manager. Are you using Homebrew, `rbenv` or `rvm`?

Comment: Using both rvm and Homebrew

Comment: `rvm list` shows what's installed and what's activated. If it keeps reverting it's possible your RVM installation isn't quite right and you need to [check the documentation](https://rvm.io). Be sure you've followed all the steps.

Comment: Or like I'll have it installed, but it goes to 2.3.7 by default. Then I do "rvm install ruby-2.5.3" and it doesn't download anything new but then shows the version as 2.5.3

Comment: It shows this "* ruby-2.3.7 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.4.2 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.4.4 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.5.3 [ x86_64 ]" So I'm guessing the * means that 2.3.7 is default

Answer (score 3):

You need to pin the [default version](https://rvm.io/rubies/default):

```
rvm use --default 2.5.3
```

Then check that's applied by opening a new shell:

```
rvm list
```

If it's not staying pinned it possible RVM isn't properly initialized in your shell. Check that the `.profile` or `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` or whatever shell you're using has the right RVM environment setup at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, setting the default worked, and I was able to remove 2 of the 3 older rubies I had installed

Comment: this worked for me, I installed higher version with rvm but it was showing old version , so after doing this , it is showing newer version

Answer (score 2):

Suggesting to work with `rvm` or `rbenv`

`rvm` - [rvm documentation](https://rvm.io/rvm/install)

**Installation:**

`RVM` - copy/paste to terminal the url below.

`\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`

Make sure to restart terminal after installing `RVM environment` has to be loaded.

**Usage:**

`rvm list` - see all installed or available ruby version in the machine.

`rvm install ruby-2.5.1` - installing ruby 2.5.1 version

`rvm use 2.5.1` - using specific version

`rvm use --default 2.5.1` - to make it default